# Issue with mirror image clone object position using fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to make a clone object on the canvas using `fabric.js`, when I am make the clone of the original object it will place the clone accurately, but when I make a clone of the previous clone object it is not placing it accurately in all directions.

Here is  [demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/759FV/14/)

**Html Code**

```
 <canvas  id="c" height="400" width="500"></canvas>
 <button id="clone_left" name="left">Left</button>
 <button id="clone_right" name="right">right</button>
 <button id="clone_top" name="top">top</button>
 <button id="clone_bottom" name="bottom">bottom</button>
```

**Script**

```
//Using i-text
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var text = new fabric.IText('Sample', {
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    fill: 'red'
});
canvas.add(text); 
document.getElementById('clone_left').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if(obj.type=='i-text')
  {
        if (fabric.util.getKlass(obj.type).async) {
            obj.clone(function (clone) {
               clone.set({left: clone.get('left') + 210});
                canvas.add(clone);
            });
        } else {
            //alert("else");
            var clone = obj.clone();
          //lone.set({left: clone.get('left') + 370});
          clone.set("angle", "180").set('flipY', true); 
          clone.set({top: clone.get('top') + 52});
          canvas.add(clone);
          canvas.renderAll();
        }
  } 
});

document.getElementById('clone_right').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if(obj.type=='i-text')
  {
        if (fabric.util.getKlass(obj.type).async) {
            obj.clone(function (clone) {
               clone.set({left: clone.get('left') + 210});
               clone.set("angle", "180").set('flipY', true);
               canvas.add(clone);
               //alert("if");
            });
        } else {
          //  alert("else right");
          var clone = obj.clone();
          clone.set({left: clone.get('left') + 250});
          clone.set("angle", "180").set('flipY', true); 
          clone.set({top: clone.get('top') + 52});
          canvas.add(clone);
        } 
     } 
});
document.getElementById('clone_top').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
 var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if(obj.type=='i-text')
  {
        if (fabric.util.getKlass(obj.type).async) {
            obj.clone(function (clone) {
              clone.set("angle", "180").set('flipX', true);
              clone.set({top: clone.get('top') - 135});
              canvas.add(clone);
            });
        } else {
            //alert("else top");
            var clone = obj.clone();
        //clone.set("angle", "180").set('flipX', true);     
       // clone.set({top: clone.get('top') - 50});
          clone.set({left: clone.get('left') + 120});
          clone.set("angle", "180").set('flipX', true); 
          canvas.add(clone);
        } 
  }  
});

document.getElementById('clone_bottom').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if(obj.type=='i-text')
  {
        if (fabric.util.getKlass(obj.type).async) {
            obj.clone(function (clone) {
              clone.set("angle", "-180").set('flipX', true);    
              clone.set({top: clone.get('top') + 135});
              canvas.add(clone);
            });
        } else {
            var clone = obj.clone();
        // clone.set("angle", "-180").set('flipX', true);   
        //clone.set({top: clone.get('top') + 50});
        clone.set("angle", "-180").set('flipX', true);  
        clone.set({top: clone.get('top') + 100});
        clone.set({left: clone.get('left') + 120});
        canvas.add(clone);
        } 
  } 

});
```

When i am make the simple clone it works good: 
[image: working snap]

But when I make a clone of the cloned object it looks like this and is not in the accurate position.You can see here the clone object made from the bottom of the clone with the blue border corner and the blue arrow representing the wrong position of that object, actually I want that cloned object below as it is of the cloned object.

[image: Getting issue with position]

Answer (score 1):

The wrong position was caused mainly by `fabric.IText` object declaration.

```
var text = new fabric.IText('Sample', {
    left: 100, // this cause translation
    top: 100, // this cause translation
    fill: 'red'
});
```

I have used `fabric.util.object.clone` instead of `obj.clone` function, and I have removed every recurrence of magic numbers, now works as expected:

**http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/3dr72sj2/4/embedded/result/**

[image]

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var text = new fabric.IText('Sample', {
    fill: 'red'
});

// the start positioning of text are set out object declaration
text.set({top: text.get('top') + 150}); 
text.set({left: text.get('left') + 200});
canvas.add(text);

document.getElementById('clone_left').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (obj.type == 'i-text') {
        var cl = fabric.util.object.clone(obj);
        cl.set('flipY', true);  
        // using the text object properties instead of magic numbers it is better to achieve the right measurement 
        cl.set({left: cl.get('left') - text.width});
        canvas.add(cl);

    }
});

document.getElementById('clone_right').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (obj.type == 'i-text') {
        var cl = fabric.util.object.clone(obj);
        cl.set('flipY', true);  
        cl.set({left: cl.get('left') + text.width});
        canvas.add(cl);

    }
});

document.getElementById('clone_bottom').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (obj.type == 'i-text') {
        var cl = fabric.util.object.clone(obj);
        cl.set('flipY', true);
        cl.set({top: cl.get('top') + text.height});
        canvas.add(cl);

    }
});
document.getElementById('clone_top').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (obj.type == 'i-text') {
        var cl = fabric.util.object.clone(obj);
        cl.set('flipY', true);
        cl.set({top: cl.get('top') - text.height});
        canvas.add(cl);

    }
});
```